# Como faço contagem de votos em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código que representa uma urna e preciso saber quem ganhou a votação no final de tudo, como posso fazer isso?

Todos os dados são inseridos pelo cliente, a única coisa fixa é a quantidade de candidatos, os votos não tem limite.

Tentei com **max** mas ele puxou o numero mais alto e não o que mais foi inserido na lista. Também gostaria de saber se tem como simplificar esse código.

```
def verificar_candidatos(dicionario, lista_candidatos, numero_voto, lista_votos):
    i = 0
    for _ in range(5):
        if dicionario[lista_candidatos[i]] == int(numero_voto):
            lista_votos.append(numero_voto)
            print(lista_candidatos[i])
        i += 1
presidentes = dict()
for _ in range(5):
    nome_candidato = input()
    numero_candidato = int(input())
    presidentes[nome_candidato] = numero_candidato
lista_votos = []
candidatos = list(presidentes.keys())
numero_candidato = list(presidentes.values())
voto_em_Branco = 0
while True:
    voto = input()
    if str(voto) == 'ACABOU' or str(voto) == 'acabou':
        break
    elif int(voto) < 0:
        voto_em_Branco += 1
        print('Voto em Branco')  
    elif int(voto) not in presidentes.values():
        print('Voto Anulado')
    else:
        verificar_candidatos(presidentes, candidatos, voto, lista_votos)
i = 0
for _ in range(5):
  print(f"{candidatos[i]}: {lista_votos.count(f'{presidentes[candidatos[i]]}')} votos(s)")
  i += 1
print('Votos em Branco:', voto_em_Branco, 'voto(s)')
```

Answer (score -1):

Para pegar quem foi o mais votado, coloque a quantidade de votos em uma lista (ou dicionário) e ordene do maior para o menor, pegue o primeiro elemento e irá ter quem foi o mais votado

no caso da lista use a sorted(list)

exemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp

```
a = (1, 11, 2)
x = sorted(a)
print(x)
```

Em relação a melhorar o código, evite usar while true, coloque sempre a sentença que irá fazer o laço sair

exemplo:

```
while str(voto) == 'ACABOU' or str(voto) == 'acabou':
   <restante do código aqui>
```

evite ficar usando "_" no for, coloque sempre ao que aquele for se refere, fica mais fácil a leitura para futuramente alguém bater o olho e ja saber o que se refere aquele laço, o mesmo para variáveis, especifique o que a variável esta fazendo, evite colocar "i" porque fica complicada a leitura, tem que ir atras das variáveis ate descobrir o que o "i" faz, colocando algo explicito, fica mais fácil ja entender de cara o que a variável faz. Se estiver usando o python 3.10+ evite ficar fazendo if elif, elif, pense em uma maneira de usar switch porque fica mais legível também.

No mais, quebre em mais funções o código para ficar melhor a leitura, ficar tudo juntinho assim as vezes fica mais complicado de ler.